# task_struct -> parent always points to root process not the actual parent

Tags: c, module, kernel

I am trying to implement a module which takes a pid as input and simply prints some properties of that process. Printing siblings' information is also a part of the module. However, when I entered a 2nd or 3rd degree leaf process, it directly returns parent with pid=1 which is the root. I cannot figure out why this happens.

Here is my code: (I know this is not the best style of coding)

```
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/pid.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>

static int pid = -1;

module_param(pid, int, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP );


int pid_init(void){

    if(pid == -1){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "No input entered!\n");
    }

    struct pid *pid_struct = find_get_pid(pid);
    struct task_struct *ptr = pid_task(pid_struct, PIDTYPE_PID);

    struct task_struct *my_parent = ptr->parent;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Parent PID: %d\n", my_parent->pid);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Parent Name: %s\n", my_parent->comm);


    printk(KERN_INFO "Current State: %ld\n", ptr->state);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Current Name: %s\n", ptr->comm);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Siblings: \n");

    struct task_struct *sib;
    struct list_head *list;

    list_for_each(list, &my_parent->children) {
        sib = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
        printk(KERN_INFO "SIbling PID: %d\n", sib->pid);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Sibling state: %ld\n", sib->state);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Sibling name: %s\n", sib->comm);
    }


   return 0;
}


void pid_exit(void){

    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing module ... \n");

}


module_init(pid_init);
module_exit(pid_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Harun Sasmaz");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("PID MODULE");
```

For example when I say: sudo insmod mymodule pid=821, parent should be 809 but program goes to 1.

```
─udisksd(809)─┬─{udisksd}(821)
              ├─{udisksd}(824)
              ├─{udisksd}(928)
              └─{udisksd}(953)
```

Comment: In Linux Kernel, parent of all the process is always Init Process. So, if you try to view the parent PID it will always give you the value 1. The init process spawns other processes and then those processes can have groups of process. So, if you want to know the PID of immediate leader of a process group then you need to access `ptr->group_leader;` instead of `ptr->parent;` in your code.

Comment: But now it cannot iterate children of group leader to list siblings

Answer (score 0):

In order to list the threads and it's PID of group of process, it is required to iterate over the threads of `group_leader` structure.
I am posting the modified code here:

```
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
#include <linux/pid.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>

static int pid = -1;

module_param(pid, int, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP );


int pid_init(void){


    if(pid == -1){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "No input entered!\n");
    }

    struct pid *pid_struct = find_get_pid(pid);
    struct task_struct *ptr = pid_task(pid_struct, PIDTYPE_PID);

    struct task_struct *leader = ptr->group_leader;
    struct task_struct *t;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Parent PID: %d\n", leader->pid);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Parent Name: %s\n", leader->comm);
    printk(KERN_INFO "PID: %d\n", ptr->pid);  
    printk(KERN_INFO "Threads: %d\n", leader->signal->nr_threads);

    for (t = next_thread(leader); t != leader; t = next_thread(t)) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "CPID: %d %s\n", t->pid, t->comm);
    }
   return 0;
}


void pid_exit(void){

    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing module ... \n");

}


module_init(pid_init);
module_exit(pid_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Harun Sasmaz");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("PID MODULE");
```